# LED strip without LED Driver

Tags: led-strip, led-driver

I have a Home Automation Motion Detector Project. I am to light a LED strip of 1meter when motion is detected. My arrangement is posted as an attachment. The transistor is attached to a microcontroller output through a resistor and diode.

My Question is: is a LED Driver compulsory in this arrangement?

[image: Led control From Microcontroller]

Another option that can be implemented is Using a Relay. The relay will act as a driver.

Please refer to the attached image and give your valuable advises

[image]

**Edit:** These are the Relay Ratings that I have found in the datasheet. These are the only rating given in the entire datasheet.

[image]

Comment: OK. Thank you. From what i read on Adafruit, a 1meter LED strip will draw about 1.2A of current. and my SMPS is capable to providing 3A current. Also, I suppose the LED strips already have Limiting resistors. So, I do not need to add an extra current limit resistor at the beginning of the LED strip right?

Comment: Um. \$1.2\:\textrm{A}\$ will need about \$100\:\textrm{mA}\$ of base drive current. Your resistor won't even come close, unless you are driving it with \$100\:\textrm{V}\$ or more. And your micro won't source \$100\:\textrm{mA}\$, anyway. You need a different circuit.

Comment: Thank you for your advise Jonk. But, I have used to same circuit before. Just that instead of the LED strip, there as a Relay attached. And that worked just fine. Am I still missing something?

Comment: Yes. A relay helps a lot. They usually don't require 1.2 A!! (You hadn't mentioned all the details, as you should have.)

Comment: You can avoid the cost of a relay, by using a TIP32 instead, though. But I think a relay is fine, too.

Comment: So, if I discard the Relay and use TIP32 transistor As the switching transistor Instead of T1 in the diagram above, that will also work fine?

Comment: Use a suitable MOSFET to switch the LED strip, not a BJT.

Comment: @Majenko You are right. How about a IRLB8721 TO220? I have a bunch of them lying around..

Comment: What voltage is your MCU IO?

Comment: @Majenko 3.2V 12mA

Comment: I would look for something with a lower threshold. That one would be fine with a 5v MCU.

Comment: @jonk: TIP32 is PNP and has a worst case Hfe of 25 at Ic = 1A, so it isn't a good fit.

Comment: @jonk I overlooked that part and assumed very high beta.

Comment: @EMFields Thanks. I'm driving it with 100 mA in the example, which is Hfe of 12. But do you have a better suggestion? (The datasheet shows decent operation at Hfe of 10 for this use, I think.)

Comment: @winny I'm showing it at Hfe of slightly less than 12 in the schematic. Not depending on high beta. In the first circuit, Q2 is estimated as operating at a high beta. But it's working as an emitter follower, so that's fine. In the 2nd circuit, I assume saturating Q2 instead. Different topology there.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to consider ways to avoid the relay (they tend to cost money and they are mechanical and wear out over time), you could consider something like this (these schematics are updated now, given the new information about the \$3.3\:\textrm{V}\$ operating voltage for your micro.):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMlZmr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The above circuit adds \$R_2\$ (which is otherwise not actually necessary) in order to distribute the power dissipation load away from \$Q_2\$ and into a resistor. If you use a TO-220 type BJT for \$Q_2\$, though, you could remove \$R_2\$ without trouble.

Another approach would be:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVwYnN.png)</sup>

This last circuit may be part of why Majenko specifically suggests using a MOSFET for \$Q_1\$. It may be difficult to support \$11\:\textrm{mA}\$ from your micro's output using this topology.

However, the first circuit I mentioned uses an emitter follower arrangement for \$Q_2\$, so it only requires \$1\:\textrm{mA}$\$ (or less) and won't tax most modern microcontroller outputs. So the need for a MOSFET is less, with the first circuit. But it still involves dissipation in the resistors and those add costs, as well.

I tend to stay away from the use of MOSFETs, as cost matters a lot to me and diverse manufacturers matter somewhat, also. However, I do use them. And this would be a good application. If you are willing to reverse the sense of your I/O, it might look like:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3hd5r.png)</sup>

This uses the IRLB8721 you mentioned. It definitely has very low drain-source resistance driven as above and would work well. (\$R_{DS(on)} \approx 10\:\textrm{m}\Omega\$ with \$V_{GS}=10\:\textrm{V}\$.) But your LEDs will be "ON" when your micro outputs a LOW. Just keep that in mind.

Majenko would prefer you use a logic level MOSFET. And for that, you may need nothing other than a small gate resistor and the MOSFET. But you'll have to select and buy one of those.

Comment: Damn Jonk!! Thank you so very much for all your help and advise. So I will do this, I will use your 3rd and last suggestion. I will Constant Pull Up my Micro pin. So that it will output a LOW when it gets from within the code. So when it outputs a low, the LED strip will turn ON. Sounds like a plan?

Comment: @shantanu Yes. You already have the MOSFET, which is "good." When you output a LOW, Q1 will be OFF. Because it is OFF. R2 can then pull up the gate on the MOSFET to about 12 V. Which should be plenty good. If you output a HIGH, Q1 turns ON and this pulls the MOSFET gate back close to ground, which should shut the MOSFET off.

Comment: Perfect. Thank You extremely very much Jonk. And also Majenko. You guys are superb.

Comment: @shantanu However, you could also just try to use the MOSFET directly, using a 220 Ohm resistor to its gate from your micro (might not even need that, either.) In this case, a HIGH output from the micro would turn the LEDs ON. The risk here is that you don't drive the gate high enough and the LEDs aren't ON as much as they might otherwise be. But it is worth an experiment, too.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. I really appreciate it. So basically, I can drive the LED strip with the above circuit (As mentioned by Mr.EM Fields) WITHOUT a LED driver right?

Comment: @shantanu Yes, that's the same circuit as my 3rd one. In effect.

Comment: @shantanu I just doin't think the 1k resistor is anything like necessary. So I disagree slightly about his choice of resistors as being an unnecessary and excessive waste of power and drive current. I'm also not sure if you are using an Arduino at 3.3 V or a micro at 5 V. (I used a 5 V assumption for my first two circuits, but provided a way for you to calculate your own resistor values if your I/O is at a different voltage.)

Comment: I am using a WiFi Module by Ogemray. Its operating voltage is 3.3V and its GPIO Outputs about 3.2V peak at 12mA current avg.

Comment: @shantanu If you are using the last circuit I mentioned, then you are fine. However, this does mean that you probably CANNOT use your existing MOSFET (IRLB8721) directly. So you probably do need something like the last circuit I mentioned if you use the MOSFET. The other two circuits I mentioned are predicated on 5V. So the resistor values need to be changed. I'll re-write them for 3.3V, to be clear.

Comment: Thank You Jonk. Also, can you please take a look at the new circuit with Relay I put up? There I have replaced the mosfet with a relay. You think the relay circuit will also work fine?

Comment: @shantanu Yes, if you are using a relay then we'd need to know the current it requires to do a safe design. But you already have it working as I understand it. So you must have gotten values close enough. If you want better, you'll need to refer to the specific relay datasheet.

Comment: it's a 12V relay with a Coil Rated Current of 33.3A

Comment: @shantanu No. I mean the current required for the COIL needed to activate the relay.

Comment: Hi. I just put up a picture that shows all the ratings of the relay I am planning to use. It mentions coil current as 33.3A. And at max power, if you calculate, it comes up to 43.3A. Please have a look

Comment: @shantanu Only 35 mA or so. That should be no problem. So it seems you already have a circuit that works for you with the relay, from what you've said already. So perhaps you don't need to use the other circuits. Up to you. (You should probably edit your question and add these things there, rather than posting up new answers every time.)

Comment: You are right. I am sorry for that. I will keep it in mind next time. And I am going to work with both circuits. Explore both of them. Atleast I learnt something very new. Thanx to you fellas!! Thank you.

Comment: For the resistor before the transistor I am using around 57mOhm resisitor. That should be fine right? Because Ic = 33.3mA, Vbe(sat) = 0.65V, MCU output voltage = 3.2V. and Hfe of transistor is 30 min.

Comment: @shantanu You need about 3 mA at the base. With, let's say, 3.2 V at your I/O pin and about 0.8 V at the base, this means 680 or 750 Ohms would be good enough to drive the relay.

Answer (score 2):

If you can invert the Arduino's output, this will work using the MOSFET and any jellybean NPNs you have on hand:

[image]

Comment: R3 will be replaced by my load i.e. the LED Strip right?

Comment: Yes.  sorry for the confusion, I'll fix it right now.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. I really appreciate it. So basically, I can drive the LED strip with the above circuit (As mentioned by Mr.EM Fields) WITHOUT a LED driver right?

Comment: @Shantanu: Yes. The circuit **is** the driver! Try it, you'll like it. :)

Comment: Hi EM. I was just curious, I thought of one more way to do the same operation. Will it be fine if I replace the MOSFET by a 12V relay?

Comment: @shantanu: A relay, wired as shown in your question, will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is a part of my (not made yet) design for a PWM dimmer for a LED strip using STM32F031. From LTSpice sims it should be good for switching times down to microseconds and won't overload STM's GPIO.

Do bear in mind it isn't tested yet.

The N-MOS is logic-level so no level switching needed.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flzZxO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>